# Using Web Audio Api AudioWorklet to grab the bits and do BPM detection from audiostream

Tags: javascript, audio-recording, web-audio-api

I am trying to get the chunks with the AudioWorklet like it is suggested by cwilso in the following link: [Using web audio api for analyzing input from microphone (convert MediaStreamSource to BufferSource)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879587/using-web-audio-api-for-analyzing-input-from-microphone-convert-mediastreamsour), but unfortunately I don´t get it running. Does somebody know, how I get the chunks from the stream with the AudioWorker, so I can analyze them? Here is my Code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
.then(function(stream) {
    /* use the stream */
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(); // define audio context
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    //connect stream to a web audio context with a MediaStreamAudioNode
    source.connect(audioCtx);
    //Use an AudioWorklet to grab the bits and do detection
    //https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/audio-worklet
    //https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/audio-worklet-design-pattern
    //https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#audioworklet
    audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule('AudioWorklet.js').then(() => {
      let bypassNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioCtx, 'bypass-processor');
    });

    //collect chunks for beat detection

    //do BPM detection

})
.catch(function(err) {
    /* handle the error */
    alert("Error");
});
        // Script in an extra file like it is explained in the api
class BypassProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
process (inputs, outputs) {
// Single input, single channel.
let input = inputs[0];
let output = outputs[0];
output[0].set(input[0]);
// Process only while there are inputs.
alert(input);
alert(output);
return false;}}); registerProcessor('bypass-processor', BypassProcessor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much processing you need to do, you could do it within the `AudioWorkletNode` itself.

If not, you'll need to pass the data from the AudioWorkletNode to the main thread using a [MessagePort](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioworkletprocessor-port)

You might also be interested in [MessagePort with AudioWorklet](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/basic/message-port.html) and [AudioWorklet with SharedArrayBuffer and Worker](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/)

Comment: I would like to process thirty seconds of the audiostream. What do I need to change in my Code to accomplish that?

Comment: how can i get chunks of audio stream within a milliseconds, just like ``MediaRecorder.start(timeslice: number)``